# Jmeter summary report on command line

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

Jmeter non-gui mode generates real time Test Results in the below format:

```
summary = 1649731 in 00:10:06 = 2721.2/s Avg:    47 Min:     9 Max: 16027 Err:   112 (0.01%)
summary +  63699 in 00:00:30 = 2123.3/s Avg:    64 Min:    12 Max:  2080 Err:     4 (0.01%) Active: 192 Started: 193 Finished: 1
summary = 1713430 in 00:10:36 = 2693.0/s Avg:    47 Min:     9 Max: 16027 Err:   116 (0.01%)
summary +  62509 in 00:00:30 = 2083.6/s Avg:    66 Min:    11 Max:  2034 Err:     1 (0.00%) Active: 192 Started: 193 Finished: 1
summary = 1775939 in 00:11:06 = 2665.6/s Avg:    48 Min:     9 Max: 16027 Err:   117 (0.01%)
summary +  69708 in 00:00:30 = 2323.5/s Avg:    45 Min:     9 Max:  2074 Err:     4 (0.01%) Active: 123 Started: 193 Finished: 70
summary = 1845647 in 00:11:36 = 2650.9/s Avg:    48 Min:     9 Max: 16027 Err:   121 (0.01%)
```

What is `summary +` and `summary =` ?

Comment: Please format your question for people to understand it clearly.

Answer (score 3):

**Summary +** are incremental for the latest summariser period

**Summary =** are cumulative for the above Summary+

```
summary + 63699 in 00:00:30 = 2123.3/s 
summary = 1713430 in 00:10:36 = 2693.0/s
```

Example 63699 in 00:00:30 = 2123.3/s means that in 30seconds Jmeter have sent 63699 requests to the server with an average throughput of 2123 requests per second.

The next iteration will start from the ahead of the cumulative time of the above summary. Ex: 00:11:06 = (00:00:30 + 00:10:36)

Comment: what about the rest of the fields?

Answer (score 3):

As per [Top 2 Techniques to Get JMeter Test Results in non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-two-techniques-get-jmeter-test-results-non-gui-mode)

> Here’s an example of what you get from the default summariser:
>
> ```
> summary +    41 in  15.4s =    2.7/s Avg:  2234 Min:   383 Max:  6974 Err: 0 (0.00%)
>
> summary +    57 in  21.5s =    2.6/s Avg:  2548 Min:   618 Max:  4528 Err: 0 (0.00%)
>
> summary =    98 in  32.5s =    3.0/s Avg:  2416 Min:   383 Max:  6974 Err: 0 (0.00%)
>
> summary +   108 in  21.8s =    5.0/s Avg:  1291 Min:   229 Max:  6317 Err: 0 (0.00%)
>
> summary =   206 in  52.5s =    3.9/s Avg:  1827 Min:   229 Max:  6974 Err: 0 (0.00%)
> ```

The lines with `summary +` are incremental for the latest summariser period, the lines with `summary =` are cumulative.  The above was with a summariser period of 20 secs, the actual periods can sometimes be longer than the specified period and the length of the very first period is somewhat random.  You get the throughput statistics as well as average, min and max response times, and how many errors were detected (assuming your JMeter test plan has assertions to detect errors).

---

If the JMeter's summariser output doesn't seem too informative to you consider running your JMeter test using [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper, it has console reporter which prints current metrics right in your terminal:

[image]

You can also configure [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html) to store results to [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/) and plot them using [Grafana](https://grafana.com/), an example dashboard can look like:

[image]